# how to configure settings of visual studio console window once and for all

Tags: visual-studio, console, window, configure

How can I change the default settings of the Visual Studio console window?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do it, given by a friend. Run cmd prompt. Click on the icon at the top. Select defaults. Enter the settings you want. Off you go!

Comment: I see this topic is 8 years old, now this does not work in Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Normal cmd settings do not apply to VS2017 output console window.